# Xcode How to remove the framework after remove the pod file

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, podfile

After I remove the pod file, I get an error of

```
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Wondering where can I remove the framework? Tried to go Targets, then go Linked Framework and Libraries. I can't see the Alamofire framework exists. Also, in the framework search path, I also can't see a path for Alamofire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to other linker flags in target->build settings. Then remove the frameworks.